# Alternative LEDs Blinking circuit(Analog) Help

Tags: led, diodes, bjt, feedback, blink

Can someone explain the operation of this circuit, I understand the basics of the BJT and its modes, but most of my confusion arises when there is some-sort of feedback loop in the circuit, my thought process breaks down, could someone help me understand things better.

I don't understand the exact operation of the capacitors in this circuit, I know they charge and discharge causing the transistors to turn on and off, but not sure how the capacitors go about doing this.

The LEDs light up alternatively, D1 and D2, the speed of alternating is adjusted through the potentiometer R3

Adjusting R3 causes the LEDs to alternatively light up faster or slower

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6mqeI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a variant of this [multivibrator](http://www.technologystudent.com/elec1/dual1.htm)